# How do I cheaply produce an infinite splittable stream of non-colliding numbers from a single seed?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, random

I need a function `split : Word64 -> (Word64, Word64)` that takes any Word64 and splits it into two different Word64s in a way that I can keep splitting children and grandchildren in any arbitrary order while avoiding a collision. That is, for any pair `sa, sb` of consecutive splittings of a seed (such as `sa = fst.split.fst.split$ seed`), `sa` must be different from `sb` with >99.99% odds.

I've thought in using a [pairing function](http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf), but that makes children exponentially bigger than parents, so, after a few splits there is an integer overflow. I need something that basically sends any value on the space of possible Word64 bits to two other values in a semi randomly fashion. Also, I need it to be as quick and simple as possible. The fewer instructions, the better. It is probably a very stupid calculation that I'm missing.

What can be used here?

*Disclaimer: I have asked similar questions before, but now I finally have a better understanding of the problem and know exactly what I need.*

Comment: Also, I'm aware of [this](http://lpaste.net/158197). But that requires the generated values to be pseudorandomish. I just need them to not collide, so it could be the most predictable thing. I guess that is not the same problem, but excuse me if it is.

Comment: I don't think this is achievable. If you want N splittings to generate distinct numbers, then they must generate 2^N distinct numbers, hence most of these must be comparable to 2^N.

Comment: I don't need that all possible splittings generate different numbers. I just need that a **small sample** of random splitting sequences is very unlikely to have a collision. (`like: sample = [sa, sb, sc, sd, se]`, where those are obtained from splitting a root seed and getting fst/snd and so on)

Comment: Basically, I have a graph rewriting system on which nodes can have children and all nodes need an unique global id. So, whenever a node reproduces, it must come up with two different ids that must be different from any other id on the graph, without global synchronization. Edit: also, I'll never have as much as 2^64 nodes, so the space will never be fully saturated. I just want a simple fair way to split values through that space.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I can't prove any statistical properties on the following, so it is just a heuristic. It is based on the [xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift.2A) family of pseudo-random sequence generators, which is known to be very fast.

Consider the [xorshift* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift.2A), here shown in C:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t x; /* The state must be seeded with a nonzero value. */

uint64_t xorshift64star(void) {
    x ^= x >> 12; // a
    x ^= x << 25; // b
    x ^= x >> 27; // c
    return x * UINT64_C(2685821657736338717);
}
```

The explanation in the wikipedia entry states:

> A xorshift* generator takes a xorshift generator, and applies an invertible multiplication (modulo the word size) to its output as a non-linear transformation.

The heuristic algorithm I suggest is:

- Give the head node some nonzero value `x`.
- For each split, run the algorithm above with `x` at the beginning as the value of the parent. However, for the return value

  - for the left child, replace the last line with `return x;` (essentially the classic `xorshift` algorithm)
  - for the right child, use the last line as stated above.

At any node *u*, take any two nonidentical descendant paths leading to distinct *v* and *w*. Then either

- *v* is a descendant of *w*, and thus at least either xorshift or xorshift* was applied at least once to the value of *w*  to obtain the value of *v*.
- *w* is a descendant of *v*, and the same argument can be made.
- neither node is a parent of the other. In this case, at least a single non-linear transformation was made along the path leading from *u* to the lowest common ancestor of *v* and *w* (possibly *u* itself).

Comment: I have no idea how that black magic works, but looks reliable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Also starting with a disclaimer: I'm not a cryptographer and this might be really bad.

However, you can try `\x -> (x*3+1, x*3+2)`. This relies on modulo-2^64 semantics for integer overflow. Quick tests didn't reveal any obvious collision patterns. The idea is that multiplication by 3 does not care about integer overflow. In particular, `3^n` is always different value from `2*3^n`, doesn't matter how big `n`.

This is the test I've done:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Int
import Text.Printf
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

split :: Int32 -> (Int32, Int32)
split x = (x * 3 + 1, x * 3 + 2)

bools bias n =
  replicateM n (randomRIO (0, 1.0) >>= \x -> if x < bias then return False else return True)

gogo bias =
  bools bias 100000 >>= \l -> do
    let things = scanl (\x b -> if b then fst (split x) else snd (split x)) 0 l
    printf "%.2f %d %d\n" bias (length things) (length $ Set.toList (Set.fromList things))
    return things

main = do
  things <- mapM gogo [0.0 :: Double, 0.05 .. 1]
  printf "all  %d %d\n" (length $ concat things) (length $ Set.toList (Set.fromList $ concat things))



0.00 100001 100001
0.05 100001 100001
0.10 100001 100001
0.15 100001 100001
0.20 100001 100001
0.25 100001 100000
0.30 100001 99997
0.35 100001 99998
0.40 100001 99999
0.45 100001 99999
0.50 100001 100001
0.55 100001 100000
0.60 100001 100001
0.65 100001 100001
0.70 100001 99998
0.75 100001 99999
0.80 100001 100001
0.85 100001 100001
0.90 100001 100001
0.95 100001 100001
1.00 100001 100001
all  2100021 2099351
```

The number of collisions seems to roughly agree with what one might expect from a random sample of that size.

Comment: This is either terribly wrong or a much better solution. I'll be researching this one. Thanks!

Comment: @MaiaVictor, so which one is it? :-)

Comment: I can't recall what I had for lunch. This was 3 years ago. Sorry you'll need to figure it out...